# I cant upload to Heroku RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, github, heroku

Hello I have a little problem, I push my project (Rails) normally on github without any problem I connect it normally to heroku and when I try to do git heroku push master, it displays this to me =>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeHTJ.png)

I saw that this is a gemfile problem, because a friend's gemfile.lock is working on my project when I try to upload

RAILS : Rails 5.2.4.5

BUNDLER : Bundler version 2.2.14

RUBY : ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin20]

Comment: please post the actual error message, and only the relevant part if you can, instead of an image

Comment: The output message seems to be telling you what you need to do.

Comment: Look at the line above the "Failed to install" line. That's what you need to do.

Comment: Hey everyone, i solved my problem by install x code select, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is with bundle install, have you done all what is expected with heroku like using the gem pg instead of sqlite3?

Comment: Hey everyone, i solved my problem by install x code select, thanks !